# Android - Cannot send data to the next activity (extending ListActivity) after pulling JSON data through AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

First and foremost, I am an android newbie.
I am creating a simple app which pulls some data from the server through a PHP script and showing them in a ListView in the next Activity. However, I find that if the script returns nothing, the app crashes. So I kept a check that only if the script returns some data, the app would switch to the next activity.
This is my code.

```
public class HomeScreen extends ActionBarActivity {

String message3;
String message_short;
String[] items;
String[] short_items;
int check = 0;

private ProgressDialog dialog;

public String readJSONFeed(String URL)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet hg = new HttpGet(URL);
    try
    {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(hg);
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
        if(statusCode == 200)
        {
            HttpEntity en = response.getEntity();
            InputStream content = en.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
            String line;
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                sb.append(line);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Log.e("JSON", "Failed to download File");
        }
    }
    catch(ClientProtocolException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

private class ReadJSONFeedTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(HomeScreen.this);
        dialog.setMessage("Downloading Notifications. Please wait . . .");
        dialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();
    }
    protected String doInBackground(String...urls)
    {
        return readJSONFeed(urls[0]);
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String result)
    {
        dialog.dismiss();
        try
        {
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
            items = new String[jsonArray.length()];
            short_items = new String[jsonArray.length()];
            for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++)
            {
                JSONObject jobj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                message3 = "SUBJECT : " + jobj.getString("subject") + "\n\n" + 
                        "DATE : " + jobj.getString("date") + "\n" + jobj.getString("time") + "\n\n"
                         + "NOTICE : " + jobj.getString("notice");
                message_short = "SUBJECT : " + jobj.getString("subject") + "\n" 
                        + "NOTICE : " + jobj.getString("notice").substring(0, 20) + "..."
                        + "\n" + jobj.getString("time");
                items[i] = message3;
                short_items[i] = message_short;

                check += 1;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_screen);
}

public void notificationPane(View view)
{

    String localhost = "http://10.0.2.2/example/json/notification.php";
    new ReadJSONFeedTask().execute(localhost);

    if(check != 0)
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(HomeScreen.this, NotificationPanel.class);
        i.putExtra("items", items);
        i.putExtra("short_items", short_items);
        startActivity(i);
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Either there is no notification to display or there might be a problem with your internet connection.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

public void recentNotice(View view)
{

    String localhost = "http://10.0.2.2/example/json/recent_notification.php";
    new ReadJSONFeedTask().execute(localhost);

    if(check != 0)
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(HomeScreen.this, NotificationPanel.class);
        i.putExtra("items", items);
        i.putExtra("short_items", short_items);
        startActivity(i);
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Either there is no notification to display or there might be a problem with your internet connection.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
}
```

The `int check` is where I check whether the server has returned any JSON data. If the `check` is not 0, it does not switch to  the next `activity`.
But problem with this code is that when I click the button, it shows me the TOAST `Either there is no notification to display or there might be a problem with your internet connection.` even before it has pulled data from the server, thus it never goes to the next Activity `NotificationPanel.class`. I understand this is due to the `AsyncTask`. What is more weird is if I keep clicking the button several times, the app suddenly switches to the next activity showing the data in `ListView`. But it doesn't always work. Is there a work around to this problem?
Please help.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just a question, how do you start fetching data? Where do you call that method, when onCreate method has no calls in it ?

Comment: `public void notificationPane(View view)` and `public  void recentNotice(View view)`. These are the two methods called when two different buttons are clicked. These are mentioned in the `android:onClick` attribute of the buttons in the `xml`.

Answer (score 0):

Move your code with if else to the last in onPostExecute. AsyncTask is still in execution when you check the result.

Comment: Yes, I tried that. But that doesn't work either. Gives the same problem. Shows me  the TOAST even before the dialog is dismissed.

Answer (score 0):

You should put this piece of code in the onPostExecute method:

```
if(check != 0)
{
    Intent i = new Intent(HomeScreen.this, NotificationPanel.class);
    i.putExtra("items", items);
    i.putExtra("short_items", short_items);
    startActivity(i);
}
else
{
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Either there is no notification to display or there might be a problem with your internet connection.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Put them after your current code and tell me if it worked.

"What is more weird is if I keep clicking the button several times, the app suddenly switches to the next activity showing the data in ListView. But it doesn't always work. Is there a work around to this problem?"

What you are saying here is prety clear. You cannot run your intent at first, because json is not yet fetched, when you click the button first few times. But if you continue clicking it, it will eventually fetch JSON and be able to go to next activity.

SO I'm prety sure what I said is what needs to be done.

**EDIT**
I'm prety sure your async task should looklike this:

```
private class ReadJSONFeedTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
@Override
protected void onPreExecute()
{
    super.onPreExecute();
    dialog = new ProgressDialog(HomeScreen.this);
    dialog.setMessage("Downloading Notifications. Please wait . . .");
    dialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.show();
}
 //no need a return statment
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
{

    try
    {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(readJSONFeed(urls[0]));
        items = new String[jsonArray.length()];
        short_items = new String[jsonArray.length()];
        for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++)
        {
            JSONObject jobj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            message3 = "SUBJECT : " + jobj.getString("subject") + "\n\n" + 
                    "DATE : " + jobj.getString("date") + "\n" + jobj.getString("time") + "\n\n"
                     + "NOTICE : " + jobj.getString("notice");
            message_short = "SUBJECT : " + jobj.getString("subject") + "\n" 
                    + "NOTICE : " + jobj.getString("notice").substring(0, 20) + "..."
                    + "\n" + jobj.getString("time");
            items[i] = message3;
            short_items[i] = message_short;

            check += 1;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result)
{




    if(check != 0)
     {
       Intent i = new Intent(HomeScreen.this, NotificationPanel.class);
       i.putExtra("items", items);
       i.putExtra("short_items", short_items);
       startActivity(i);
     }
    else
     {
     Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Either there is no notification to display or there might be a problem with your internet connection.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

dialog.dismiss();
}
}
```

Comment: Yes, I tried that too, putting this piece of conditional statement after the try catch block in onPostExecute. But the same problem exists. If I had some problem with the PHP script, I would have checked, but the script works just fine, and more over my app sometimes gets the data and switches to the next activity, meaning my script is fine. Please help.

Comment: I made an edit to my answer. Try doing what I  proposed

Comment: just a question, what do I do with the line  `return readJSONFeed(urls[0]);` that is already in my  `doInBackground`

Comment: if you check his update, the readJSONFeed is still your JSONArray. the diference is you are doing all on background, and startactivity on postexecute.

Comment: I proposed a little bit different code. It does the same thing prety much. It will make a new JSONArray from returned data.
Work around it is next: String json = readJSONFeed(urls[0]); JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);

Comment: `return type is incompatible with AsyncTask<String, Void, String>` due to the `void` return type of `doInBackground`. So I changed the return type of `doInBackground` to `String` and returned `null`. Code does not give  any problem but the problem with the app  persists.

Comment: Just change this line of code, and put all tree Voids: private class ReadJSONFeedTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>

Comment: Upon doing that it gives the error `ReadJSONFeedTask must implement the inherited abstract method AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>.doInBackground(Void...)` :(

Comment: Well implement needed methods and try doing it then

Comment: Ofcourse, you need to add "@Override" before implemented methods. I made an update to my answer, check it out

Comment: `The method onPostExecute(String) of type ReadJSONFeedTask must override or implement a supertype method` so I removed the `@Override` and then it gives the warning `The method onPostExecute(String) from the type ReadJSONFeedTask is never used locally`. Shouldn't it be used to dismiss the dialog?

Comment: try with  @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result).
HINT: Void as a parameter, not String.

Comment: Could you come to chat please?

Comment: I am sending a string in `execute()`. I cannot give `Void... params` in `doInBackground()`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64231/discussion-between-sajib-acharya-and-stebra).

Comment: I think this chat on comments has gone too long. You dont have to pass a string as a parameter in execute. You can make a global variable that will store the value and read it later.
Maybe it would be the best to start a new question with the code you already have.
OR just try and go back, without changing anything and just putting the earlier mentioned line of code in onPostExecute, because that's the thing you need to do in order to fix the problem you had in the forst place